# Creating build from Build->Flutter->Build APK can generate build without colors and data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a flutter project when I am trying to generate my APK from Build->Flutter->Build APK option it will not showing proper UI with colour and content.

You can refer to the below-mentioned image.

But When I am trying to generate build from the Android folder open on New Window and generate the build from there will loads UI with colour and content properly.

When I am trying to generate build from Flutter Window it was showing following command on Message TAB:

`"C:\Flutter SDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" --no-color build apk`

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong over here, or what is something I am skipping here?

You can consider my flutter sdk version by the following image.

[image]

Even after resolving this Android toolchain issue, I have tried creating build using `flutter build apk` and `flutter --color build apk` but still after generating the build getting the same UI issues.

Comment: what IDE do you use for build?

Comment: did you try to run `flutter clear` before the build ?

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat I am using android studio as IDE.

Comment: @GNassro let me try with that option `flutter clear`.

Comment: @GNassro Yes, I have tried with `flutter clean` command also, but the issue still remain the same.

Comment: have you tried to run from comand line: `flutter build apk` ?

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat Yes, I have tried with the command line too. but still getting the same issue.

Comment: can you please update your question with `flutter doctor -v` output?

Comment: Ok. Can you try to solve that `Android toolchain` issue and build the apk again ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233787/discussion-between-kishan-sharma-and-ovidiu-usvat).

Comment: @OvidiuUşvat Yes, I have solved that `toolchain` issue and again tried to build APK from IDE and command prompt too.. I have tried to figure out the issue by some other screen also with the same libs used among of classes, but still couldn't able to figure out the issue.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after lot of research and test&try's I am getting solution for this. Please refer to below link:

[github issue for grey screen on release build](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53482)

Here, they have given proper explanation about the issue:
On debug build we have the red screen for rendering layouts same way on the release build that returns with grey screen.

For my case I have found `GestureDetector` to `Flexible` widget which is wrong.

Hierarchy for my widgets is:

```
GestureDetector
   ⮑Flexible
      ⮑Container
         ⮑Icon
```

This is wrong, we have to take `gestureDetector` `onTap` event for the `Container` rather than `Flexible`.